# Arrancar una aplicacion programada en java para android en el startup

Tags: java, android

he rescrito mi pregunta y en esta ocasión seré mas especifico. Mi problema en que quiero hacer que mi aplicación se inicie cada vez que inicie mi teléfono. Para ello tengo un fichero java llamado `bootreceiver.java` que tengo lo siguiente:

```
package my.app.client;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public final String TAG = BootReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "BOOT Complete received by Client !");

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, Client.class);
            serviceIntent.setAction(BootReceiver.class.getSimpleName());
            context.startService(serviceIntent);

        }
    }

}
```

Entonces lo que necesito saber es tengo que indicarle en mi launcheractivity o que pasos debo tomar para que mi bootreceiver me encienda la aplicación cada vez que encienda mi móvil. En cuanto a lo del manifest lo entiendo es solo añadir:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name="my.app.client.BootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

En mi caso el nombre de mi clase es BootReceiver por lo que tendría que poner:

```
<receiver android:name="BootReceiver">
```

Esto lo pondré en el manifest pero no sé que tenga que poner en mi launcheractivity o que tenga que hacer con bootreceiver solo tengo que añadirlo al manifest o tengo que hacer algo más?

He estado probando en mi telefono y `muchas veces falla y no se arranca la aplicación` hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

logcat:

```
01-01 00:04:02.360: E/Trace(1464): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 00:04:02.410: W/asset(1464): Asset path /data/app/my.app.client-1.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
01-01 00:04:02.780: W/asset(1464): Asset path /data/app/my.app.client-1.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
01-01 00:04:02.820: D/AndroidRuntime(1464): Shutting down VM
01-01 00:04:02.820: W/dalvikvm(1464): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acd930)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver my.app.client.receiver.BootReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.app.client.receiver.BootReceiver" on path: /data/app/my.app.client-1.apk
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2357)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.app.client.receiver.BootReceiver" on path: /data/app/my.app.client-1.apk
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2352)
01-01 00:04:02.830: E/AndroidRuntime(1464):     ... 10 more
01-01 00:05:47.000: I/Process(1464): Sending signal. PID: 1464 SIG: 9
```

Si reformulo la pregunta es para que me expliqueis que estoy haciendo mal desde el logcat. Porque me muestra not found si en my manifest tengo mi clase..

He intentado tambien con esto y no ha funcionado:

agrega la clase BootReceiver dentro de otro paquete, por ejemplo:

```
<receiver android:name="my.app.client.receiver.BootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**El proyecto es**, que modifico con fines educativos:

[Este el proyecto para importar, cliquear aqui](https://ufile.io/qit8c)

La aplicación se llama ZMaster Clean Pro(La aplicación aparece al final), es una aplicación cliente, esta en fichero .zip para que lo podais **IMPORTAR TANTO EN ANDROID COMO ECLIPSE**-
El startup esta puesto como servicio, la cuestión es que cuando abro mi aplicación es visible, pero cuando reinicio en el startup nunca se abre, sino la abro yo. Por lo que deberá ser visible el layout de mi aplicación cuando encienda mi móvil. Si la poneis como activity os devolverá un error en el logcat como cite.

Comment: probaste haciendo un clean del proyecto desde la opción Build del menu?

Comment: El error dice que no encuentra la clase "my.app.client.receiver.BootReceiver", pero veo que la clase está definida como "my.app.client.BootReceiver" sin ese "receiver" intermedio. Ese error debe estar relacionado con esta línea: <receiver android:name="my.app.client.receiver.BootReceiver">. Habria que quitar el ".receiver." intermedio.

Comment: te devuelve el mismo error si le pones esto? receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"> Debería funcionar, cuando haces esto va a buscar la clase al directorio de tu app, en este caso a my.app.client y debería encontrarla

Comment: Agrega tu proyecto, el link no puede abrir el archivo

Comment: Hola subi el proyecto de nuevo, perdón por la tardanza.

Answer (score 9):

El error es el siguiente:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "my.app.client.receiver.BootReceiver" on path:
>   /data/app/my.app.client-1.apk 01-01 00:04:02.830:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1464):

debes de definir en el receiver el paquete y clase correcta, al parecer debe ser:

```
<receiver android:name="my.app.client.BootReceiver">
```

---

Para que se ejecute tu aplicación al iniciar completamente tu dispositivo (BOOT_COMPLETED), es importante agregues el permiso:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Habilites el receiver y agregues el intent-filter correspondiente para iniciar la aplicación al iniciar completamente tu dispositivo:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Si defines la ejecución de un BroadcastReceiver desde tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, no necesitas iniciar un servicio, puedes iniciar directamente la Activity principal de tu aplicación, por lo tanto la clase `BootReceiver` sería:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BootUpReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG,  "* onReceive()");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**Recuerda que la inicialización completa (BOOT_COMPLETED), tarda unos segundos después de que ves el dispositivo encendido, así que no desesperes.**

Agrego un [**ejemplo completo**](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-start-app-on-BOOT_COMPLETED)

Comment: hice eso pero siempre me muestra the system process has stoped y luego cuando le doy a wait me muestra unfortunately, my.app.client has stopped . Le añadi el paquete y puse el bootreceiver y cambie el manifest como indicastes pero no funciono. puse el logcat de nuevo por si acaso.,

Comment: Imagino eliminaste la aplicacion primeramente? Es importante el uso del LogCat para identificar los detalles, muestra , my.app.client has stopped pero que detalle se muestra.

Comment: Si probe con eso y todo y volvi a probar por si acaso , pero me muestra el mismo mensaje te subi los detalles de nuevo del logcat por si acaso.

Comment: @OmarOmar hola he estado un poco ocupado, en la noche te ayudo a resolver este problema.

Comment: gracias !!!!!!.

Comment: @OmarOmar listo!

Comment: el ejemplo que pusistes no es un proyecto de eclipse es de android studio ok intentaré poner tu paso nuevo en BroadcastReceiver a ver que tal.

Comment: ohhh usas Eclipse para desarrollar android, te recomiendo uses lo oficial que es android Studio. Trata "importando" el proyecto a eclipse, de cualquier puedes crear un proyecto en eclipse y agregas únicamente las clases y la configuración del AndroidManifest.xml que comento.

Comment: Hola intente importar el proyecto en eclipse y no se puede? tal vez androidstudio no sea importable? Intente tambien hacerlo repitiendo eso pero sigue sin coger en el startup.

Comment: Si se puede al parecer pero parece algo complejo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481915/how-to-import-android-studio-project-in-eclipse  Porque no estas usando Android Studio si Google dio por obsoleto el uso de plugins para eclipse u otras ides?

Comment: porque eclipse no me coge tantos recursos como android studio, hice los cambios que indicastes todos pero no se porque cuando arranco mi emulador no me arranca la aplicacion

Comment: siempre me muestra lo mismo application has stopped i el logcat lo puse y hice todos los cambios aun así sigue pasando lo mismo intenta, pero al final en el arranque se para y no lo arranca.

Comment: application has stopped y el mensaje en la consola?

Comment: esk creo k al ponerla como servicio (como servicio no muestra ningun error) la arranca como segundo plano y nunca la abre(quiero decir que mi aplicacion nunca me es visible cuando enciendo mi movil ya que debería abrirla y ser visible cada vez que encienda el movil) y cuando  arranco la Activity en lugar de ponerlo como servicio como tu me citastes es cuando me devuelve ese mensaje unfournately the application has stopped. y el logcat lo puedo resubir otra vez. También podría subir el proyecto y tu le echas un ojo en el tiempo libre del que pudiera, actualizare el post lo antes posible.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes agregar mensajes en los métodos del servicio para saber si fueron llamados, sube tu proyecto y lo reviso con gusto!

Comment: Vale ya pusé el proyecto al final del texto verás todos los detalles y el enlace de mi proyecto en eclipse. gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 4):

> **Ante todo, considera la siguiente Nota importante:**
>
> Debido a motivos de seguridad, Android no arrancará de forma
>   automática ninguna aplicación sin haberla lanzado antes de forma
>   manual **al menos una vez**. Después de ejecutarla de forma manual por
>   primera vez, la aplicación podrá arrancar de forma automática cada vez
>   que el sistema arranque.

---

**Ahora, revisemos el asunto paso por paso:**

Cuando el sistema Android arranca, se envía un evento de arranque completo. Se puede escuchar y capturar este evento para tomar acciones específicas, tales como el inicio automático de una actividad o servicio.

Como ya se ha dicho en otras respuestas, algunos permisos son necesarios.

Si sigues estos pasos debería funcionar:

**Paso 1**

En el `AndroidManifest.xml` dar a la aplicación el permiso  `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` justo antes del nodo `application`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**Paso 2**

En el mismo `AndroidManifest.xml`, dentro del nodo `application` definir la Activity que se iniciará automáticamente cuando Android arranque.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Paso 3**

Siempre en el `AndroidManifest.xml`, dentro del nodo `application`, registrar el escuchador del Reciever para el evento de carga completo (boot complete event):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyBootReceiver"
    android:label="IniciarMyBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Paso 4**

Crear la clase receptora que escuchará el evento de arranque completado. Esta clase puede extender de la clase abstracta `BroadcastReceiver`, cuyo método `onReceive()` será llamado cuando el arranque del dispositivo se haya completado. También sería importante que **esta clase se encuentro en el mismo paquete que la clase Main**.

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Para más detalles, puedes consultar este enlace (en inglés): [Auto-start custom Android applications](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001546/task/android/t_faq_autostart_custom_android_applications.htm#StartAppAfterAndroidBoot)

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano he intentado todos los pasos que colocaste al pie de la letra, en android 7 funciona perfecto, pero en android 8, 9 o 10 no funciona. Alguna sugerencia. Gracias

Comment: Hola @Isabel, después de Android 7, se necesita activar `directBootAware="true"` en el archivo manifest y modificar el código para el boot receiver, [revisa este ejemplo de Android](https://github.com/android/security-samples/blob/master/DirectBoot/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/directboot/BootBroadcastReceiver.java) (en el `if` podrás ver la forma de escribir código para versiones anteriores y posteriores). Para más detalles, puedes ver también la [documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot?hl=es-419).

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano gracias por tu sugerencia. Intente lo que me sugeriste, el directBootAware="true" en el Manifest y segui el ejemplo incluso vi otros ejemplos pero aun asi no me funciona, hasta android 7.0 funciona perfecto, pero de 8.0 hacia arriba no funciona y no entiendo por qué

Answer (score 2):

El AndroidManifest es sencillo lo que tiene que tener, el permiso para poder ejecutarlo al encender el teléfono y el receiver:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

y la definicion del receiver:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> //Esto lo he usado para un servicio, no se si te hará falta para arrancar una aplicación
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Fíjate que en android:name del receiver empieza con un punto (.BootReceiver)
Ahora sólo tienes que arrancar la actividad desde la clase BootReceiver como te ha indicado @JorgeSys.

Te tienes que asegurar que puedes iniciar la actividad Cliente desde un BroadcastReceiver, porque es fácil que te de un fallo si no lo has preparado bien (si intentas recoger datos del intent o algo así), para comprobarlo muestra un mensaje con un Toast al iniciar el cliente o algo que puedas ver si el fallo está en el BootReceiver o en la clase Cliente.

Comment: Si esto no te funciona estaría bien que contestases y dijeses que fallo te da.

Comment: ya mencione el error en el logcat, y subi un ejemplo de mi proyecto (por si acaso). El error es ese cuando `arranco la aplicación en el startup como servicio no devuelve error, pero nunca se me abre la aplicación y si lo arranco directamente el activity me devuelve el mismo error del logcat que ya subi`, ya hice todos los pasos, segui vuestras indicaciones pero el mensaje es el mismo. Gracias por tu interes!

Comment: Te entra en el método onReceive() del BootReceiver??? Si te entra prueba a sustituirlo por este código:  
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "BOOT Complete received by Client !");

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);  //Aquí pone el nombre de la actividad que quieres abrir
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

Comment: Y dime si así te funciona o te sigue dando error. Y define el receiver así en el manifest:  
    
    <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>  
   Prueba esto y comenta como te ha ido

Comment: No me cabía todo en un comentario, prueba las 2 cosas a la vez, tanto modificar el método onReceive y a modificar el Manifest para dejarlo como te digo. No desesperes, al final todo sale